# check input value after post

Tags: php, emoticons

I have test code

```
$chatText = "Hello world :D";

$chatText = str_replace(":D","<img src='happy.jpg' width='20' height='20' alt='Big Smile' />",$chatText);

echo $chatText;
```

basically what it does is replace the `:D` with an `image`. 
What I actually wanted to do is after clicking submit from a `<textarea>` -replace input value i.e emoticons (image) after post. 
How do I check user's input value to check to see if they have type these characters for example

```
":-)"
```

Comment: exactly as you do above but you have to put a post  check in first so it only does the replacement if there's been a post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829848/emoticon-replacement-php

Comment: use regex /[:\-)D] to replace the string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to check as str_replace will replace everything it matches, only check if the post isn't empty.

```
<?php
if($_POST['textarea_name']!=""){
    $text = $_POST['textarea_name'];
    $chatText = str_replace(":D","<img src='happy.jpg' width='20' height='20' alt='Big Smile' />",$text);
    echo $chatText;
}
?>
```

Check this out for more detailed replacement using arrays;

[Emoticon Replacement - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829848/emoticon-replacement-php?lq=1)

Comment: Always use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting user contents to a web page to prevent XSS.

Comment: But he's echoing out an image tag, that would turn all < into &lt; and > into &gt; which would render the image tag as normal text...

Comment: Then use `hmtlspecialchars` *before* the replacement takes place.

Comment: @Dom `$chatText = str_replace(":D","<img src='happy.jpg' width='20' height='20' alt='Big Smile' />",htmlspecialchars($text));`

Comment: But what about this smiley -> `:> - big grin` ? That would become :&gt; and wouldn't be picked up by the script.

Comment: Then replace `:&gt;` with an image.

Comment: or better `$chatText = str_replace(htmlspecialchars(":D"),"<img src='happy.jpg' width='20' height='20' alt='Big Smile' />",htmlspecialchars($text));` to maintain readability

Comment: @ejay: Fair enough, but in an array with hundreds(?) of emoticons, would it be worthwhile or efficient to do an array walk with htmlspecialchars?

Comment: If you've hundreds of emoticons in array then you can compromise readability over performance :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would work correctly for you,

```
foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v) {
    $_POST[$k] = str_replace(":D","<img src='happy.jpg' width='20' height='20' alt='Big Smile' />",$v);
}
```

That would simply process and $_POST values submitted, in which what i'm gathering is you're using a chat box, so it should only process such message box, Thus meaning it will replace and **:D** characters within these text boxes.